# Npgsql - EF6 : Nested FirstOrDefault() on navigation property subquery throws "Not Implemented" Exception

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql, entity-framework-6.1

Structure is basic. I have a "App" Parent which has Many "PositionData" children.
I want to retrieve some basic data for the "App" Along with the Last "PositionData" of that App in a single query.

The Query

```
            var data = context.Apps.Where(a => a.Id == appId).
            Select(c => new {
                DeviceInfo=c.Device,
                LastPosition=c.PositionData.OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault() 
            }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Executing the following command throws "System.NotImplementedException"

To make sure that exception is thrown only in case of a subquery, i broke this into 2 queries  and it works perfectly fine.

```
            var tempObj = context.Apps.Where(a => a.Id == appId).SingleOrDefault();
            var data=new {
                DeviceInfo=tempObj.Device,
                LastPosition=tempObj.PositionData.OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateCreated)).FirstOrDefault() 
            };
```

I have been searching for many days,also visited pg foundry forums but no solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Opened the Issue at the Npgsql Git Hub Repository. And it seemed that this error was caused indeed by a not Implemented Npgsql Feature.

They have now implemented the feature and merged it to the master branch.
Downloading Npgsql and NpgsqlEntityFramework .dll versions >= 2.2 will fix the issue . 
ALTHOUGH this fix uses the "Lateral" sql keyword which was introduced in  PostgreSQL v9.3 so that Postgresql Version is also needed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have to say, I’m really no postgresql expert. This problem is definitely a bug or at least a functional limitation of the npgsql provider. With the Sql Servier provider this statement works as expected, although it creates a really ugly and slow TSql statement.

```
 var data = context.Apps.Where(a => a.Id == appId).
            Select(c => new {
                DeviceInfo=c.Device,
                LastPosition=c.PositionData.OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault() 
            }).SingleOrDefault();
```

The following statement is obviously much bigger than yours but believe it or not the Store statement is much smaller and better optimized. The result should be the same as long as you ensure that the AppId and DateCreated combination In the PositionData table is unique.

```
var data = from a in context.Apps
           join pd in context.PositionData.GroupBy(p => p.AppId)
               .Select(p => new { AppId = p.Key, Date = p.Max(x => x.DateCreated) })
               on a.Id equals pd.AppId into pdgrp
           from lpd in pdgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join p in context.PositionData on lpd equals new { AppId = p.AppId, Date = p.DateCreated } into pgrp
           from lp in pgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where a.Id == appId
           select new {
               DeviceInfo = a.Device,
               LastPosition = lp
           };
```

Maybe this statement translates on Postresql too

Update: Some Performance indicators.

I've tested on a local SQL 2012 with really fast ssds. For the first Version the SQL Server Provider creates an OUTER APPLY Statement for the second one two LEFT OUTER JOINS. TestData was 15 000 Apps and 150 000 PositionData entries.

```
                 join                      outer apply  
                 reads     duration        reads    duration
all rows          1528          519       444434         912
single row          68            0           35           0
```

after adding the required unique Index on (AppId ASC, DateCreated DESC)

```
all rows           884          220        49875         180
single row          28            0           15           0
```

Comment: It may translates in TSQL Faster and be Smaller but how about pure SQL execution performance?

Comment: Well, it depends on how many rows you have in your tables and how many you want to select.
I’ve updated my answer with the performance values… but keep in mind. This values are from a local sql 2012 running on a really fast SSD. On another system the reads have much more impact than on my system.